# Comparing Enum Values within IronPython

Tags: c#, enums, ironpython

Within an IronPython script, I'm trying to compare the property (of type `Grade`) of an object (created in C#) with one of the possible values of the `Grade` enum. So for example:

```
if (myObject.TotalGrade == Grade.Fail):
```

Now, I have set a breakpoint after obtaining both of these values, and I can indeed verify that both of them hold a 'Fail'; however, the check fails and the program moves on to the next clause. Is the python equality operator not suitable for C# enums?

Additional info: I have imported the `Grade` enum from my C# as shown below.

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFile("mydll.dll")
from mydll import Grade
```

Comment: Not sure why they wouldn't compare equal, but apparently enums are [implemented as boxed types](http://lists.ironpython.com/pipermail/users-ironpython.com/2005-August/000915.html) in IronPython -- it seems you have two different objects for the same enum value. You can work around this by comparing the underlying values directly via `myObject.TotalGrade.value__ == Grade.Fail.value__`.

Comment: @Cameron Wow, I don't know how you found that, but man is that exchange of emails priceless. Thanks for solving this mystery. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Added an answer. As for the mailing list, I just Googled around a bit regarding IronPython enums ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested, my comment as an answer:

I'm not sure why they wouldn't compare equal, but apparently [enums are implemented as boxed types in IronPython](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/ironpython-users/2005-August/000915.html) -- it seems you have two different objects for the same enum value in this case.

You can work around this by comparing the underlying values directly like so:

```
if myObject.TotalGrade.value__ == Grade.Fail.value__:
    pass  # your code here...
```

Comment: I am also puzzled why it doesn't work for estebro. The workaround is valid. I have created a snippet of the problem as I understand it and it works as expected https://github.com/paweljasinski/ironsnips/tree/master/dotnetenums

Comment: @Pawel: Hmm, odd that that works and the OP's doesn't. Perhaps there's a nuance like multiple IronPython hosting contexts or multiple app domains? The last IronPython bug I tracked down took my 7 hours, so I'm disinclined to go hunting for this (more subtle) one :-)

Comment: I can't hunt if I can't reproduce.

Comment: Hmm... I will @PawelJasinski's code a try and report back.